# How to uninstall 8.10 while keeping 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, shutdown, uninstall, 8.04

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 11.04 with 8.10 already installed and since then my Dell VOSTRO laptop gets shuts down automatically every half an hour. Although I am using the latest version (currently 11.04) I did not uninstall 8.10 while (as per the guiding option of Ubuntu). Since this installation I am facing the sudden shut downs often.

Hence I want to remove the older version from my system. How can I do this?

Comment: Could the shutdown issue have something to do with overheating?

Answer (score 1):

I reckon they are both in different partitions. You could delete the 8.10 partition after doing the proper backup and telling grub to update itself since 8.10 is no longer available do to "unforeseen circumstances" = Formatted Partition ;)

But a couple of things. The shutting down I am pretty sure is not related to the 8.10/11.04 relation. I recommend you check the hardware first and maybe do a `dmesg` to see if something comes up that tells you the cpu is frying, the hard drive is dying or something dramatic that says this is the problem.

Comment: Agreed. You need to find out what's making 11.04 shut down. Dual booting isn't causing this.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to delete 8.10 partition and update your GRUB entries. You can do this with a GRUB rescue CD or USB key. I use [Hiren’s Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/).